# Does the UK have a border control contact point for check-in staff?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

Australia and New Zealand have dedicated border control contact points that check-in staff can call to receive clearance if there is uncertainty whether a passenger is admissible at the destination.

Does the UK have such a phone number that can be seen anywhere at all on the Internet?

Comment: If there is such a number I doubt it would be published on the net where it would be abused ...

Comment: @brhans The Aussie and NZ numbers are published in online manuals which are meant to be used by check-in staff

Comment: @Coke that doesn't mean everyone is as stupid ;)

Comment: Seems like what you are really asking is: does UK border control run a phone service providing definitive information about visas/immigration? To which the answer is, no, they prefer to let random people on the internet take care of it.

Comment: @user16259 Not really. I know the phone numbers to border control at Heathrow T3 and T5, but doubt that's who check-in staff would call, as such contact points tend to be centralised.

Comment: @Coke I think your question is going to be quite hard to answer, as no one is going to trawl every unindexed gov.uk page, PDF or document just to make sure no number exists... the only definitive answer is if someone posts a "yes, here..." but I doubt that will be the case.  I have no doubt a phone number exists, but whether it's available on the internet is the key part of your question - my thoughts would be that such a phone number is kept very close indeed.

Comment: Sometimes these checks are done via the reservations systems / telex / even email.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [Australia](https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/crossing-the-border/passenger-movement/advance-passenger-processing) and [New Zealand](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/assist-migrants-and-students/other-industry-partners/airlines) use an interactive Advance Passenger Information system known as Advance Passenger Processing (APP).  Under APP, check-in staff are required to verify a passenger's immigration status directly with government systems, which will then respond with a board/do not board message.

The contact numbers exist for check-in staff to call to resolve any issues with the APP process.  For example, a passenger may check in using a different (newer) passport from the one they specified when they applied for a visa.  The contact centre would be able to transfer the visa across to the new passport number so that the APP process can be completed successfully. A member of the public would not be able to get assistance from calling these numbers as they do not have access to the APP system.

As far as I know, the UK does not use interactive Advance Passenger Information systems, and relies on airlines performing manual checks.  Therefore it would make sense for them not to have (or not to have publicised) contact numbers for clearance queries.

Comment: "A member of the public would not be able to get assistance from calling these numbers as they do not have access to the APP system." While technically correct, I once called the Australian number to find out how the system would react in a specified case. I apologised for calling them, explaining that the Department of Immigration folks were absolutely useless, whereby I got the answer needed